# Deleting blank lines

Tags: python, count, txt

Python issues:
I need some help to figure it out why this code is printing 3 lines with a blank line between them. I want it to print every contact of a .txt starting with a specific letter.
For example, if Z is = A, it will print:

Ariana

SSN:132664979

+1356974664

Abigail

SSN: 2658978133

+5765613197

..And so on with all contacts starting with "A".
I don't know how to delete those blank spaces between each line with information.I want the code to print something like this:

Ariana
SSN:132664979
+1356974664
Abigail
SSN: 2658978133
+5765613197
...so on

I'd like to clarify that the .txt doesn't have any blank space between the data. So it is something the code is doing.

````
    Z=input("Enter the letter:")
    archive = open("agenda.txt", "r").readlines()
    print("List of people starting with that letter:")
    for i,line in enumerate(archive):
        if line.startswith(Z):
            print(archive[i])
            print(archive[i+1])
            print(archive[i+2])```



Thank you for your help.
````

Comment: Would you please post a short example of the input data?

Comment: Please add it to the question with its original formatting

Comment: The lines of data you're getting from `readlines()` already end with a newline character.  `print()` outputs that newline, and then adds one of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.readlines()` method, the lines will always end with a new line character(`\n`), these characters are treated as strings and not interpreted when not specifically using `print()` method.

Meaning the newline will be displayed as '\n'.

However when using `print()` these characters will be interpreted and will be displayed as new lines. Hence the empty lines.

The best solution would be replacing this line:

```py
archive = open("agenda.txt", "r").readlines()
```

With this:

```py
archive = open("agenda.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
```

`.read()` method returns all lines at once, `.splitlines()` splits on linebreak, it splits the result of read() into a list, with each line as an element.

And all the lines will not end with `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

`.readlines()` includes the newline (`'\n'`) character at the end of each line. I prefer to `.strip()` this when you read in the file.

```
with open('agenda.txt') as file:
    archive = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
```

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know that .readlines() includes the NEWLINE CHARACTER AT THE END OF EACH LINE. That's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(archive[i].strip())
print(archive[i+1].strip())
print(archive[i+2].strip())
```

use .strip() to remove new lines (\n)